# Mapping of the eigenvector of eigenvalue 1 to a different matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M \in (0,1)^{n\times n}$ be an irreducible and primitive column stochastic matrix. Then for the Perron theorem, $\exists x^* : Mx^* = x^*$.

We want to build a matrix $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, K=MI_{\theta}$ (where $I_{\theta}$ is a diagonal matrix with elements on the diagonal equal to $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$) such that $K\vec{1} = \vec{1}$.

Since M is also invertible, we can compute $\theta = M^{-1}\vec{1}$.

Is there a relation between $x^*$ and $\theta$?
How can I compute $\theta$ in function of $x^*$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $M$ is full rank it admits a base of auto-vectors $v_1,..,v_n$ for its auto-values $\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n$.

Let $a_1,..,a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ be the coordinates such that:
$\vec{1} = a_1v_1 + .. + a_nv_n$ and $b_1,..,b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$\theta = b_1v_1 + .. + b_nv_n$

$M\theta = \vec{1} = b_1Mv_1 + .. + b_nMv_n = \lambda_1b_1v_1 + .. + \lambda_nb_nv_n \implies b_1=\frac{a_1}{\lambda_1} $

Since $v_1 = |v_1|x^*$ and $\lambda_1 = 1$, then 
$\theta = a_1|v_1|x^* + \sum_{i=2}^n b_iv_i = nx^* + \sum_{i=2}^n b_iv_i$

Note that $\lim_{k\to \infty} M^k\theta =\lim_{k\to \infty} nx^* + \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_i^kb_iv_i = nx^*$ as $\lambda_i < 1 \forall i = {1,..,n} $

Being $Mnx^* = nx^*$, asymptotically $\theta = nx^*$